# Creating a polygon with Point Cloud

Tags: point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I am trying to create a polygon with Point Cloud Library. It shows an error 
that no matching argument list is found. 
Here is my code :

pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer::addPolygon(cloud);

Thank you for any suggestions...

Comment: What is the type of the variable "cloud"? Without this information nobody can help. Probably after finding that out and checking the signature of the addPolygon function you will solve the problem yourself.

Comment: The type of the variable cloud is pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>:: Ptr cloud..I think the mismatch of ConstPtr and Ptr is the problem.. However I couldn't solve it. I have a basic knowledge of C++..

Comment: pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
//fill the cloud. 
 // generate the data 
 
 pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer::addPolygon(cloud);// this line shows error..
      
 pcl::visualization::CloudViewer viewer("Some_Viewer");
 viewer.showCloud(cloud);
 while(!viewer.wasStopped())
 {
 }


 system("PAUSE");
 return EXIT_SUCCESS;

Comment: What happens if you explicitly template the function - e.g. addPolygon<pcl::PointXYZ> (cloud) or fill in the other default parameters e.g. addPolygon<pcl::PointXYZ> (cloud,"poly",0); ?

Comment: I have tried this earlier before this post.
It shows the same error. 
I found another way of creating shapes with 
PCLPainter 2D class.

Answer (score 1):

Had same error, solved with .

```
pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer::addPolygon(cloud);
```

to

```
pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer::addPolygon<pcl::PointXYZ>(cloud);
```

Make sure you are using pcl::PointXYZ.
e.g. if you create your cloud data like this,

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr cloud
```

then you need to use pcl::PointXYZRGB

Answer (score 0):

define of addPolygon:

```
template <typename PointT> bool
pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer::addPolygon (
  const typename pcl::PointCloud<PointT>::ConstPtr &cloud,
  const std::string &id, int viewport)
{
  return (!addPolygon<PointT> (cloud, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, id, viewport));
}
```

We must specify the type of function template:

```
viewer.addPolygon<pcl::PointXYZ>(cloud);
```

here is my example:

```
void PclVisualize(std::string filename)
{
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud = 
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>());
    pcl::io::loadPCDFile<pcl::PointXYZ>(filename,*cloud);
    
    pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer viewer("pclviewer");
    viewer.setBackgroundColor(0,0,0);
    viewer.addPointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>(cloud,"pclviewer");
    viewer.setPointCloudRenderingProperties(pcl::visualization::PCL_VISUALIZER_POINT_SIZE,1,"pclviewer");
    viewer.addCoordinateSystem(1.0);
    viewer.initCameraParameters();
    viewer.addPolygon<pcl::PointXYZ>(cloud);
    while(!viewer.wasStopped())
    {
        viewer.spinOnce(1000);
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::duration<long double,std::milli>(200));
    }
}
```